# Website doesn't function in Mozilla but does in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

As the title suggests my website, [www.contrabang.com](http://www.contrabang.com) doesn't seem to function in Moxilla. But it functions fine in Google Chrome, and a bit less fine in IE. This is the first time I've made a website before so apologies in advance if I've made any beginner errors. But I cant seem to find a solution.

HTML is as follows:

```
             <div class="icons">
              <a class="twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/kadeemlaurie"></a>
              <a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Contrabang/127379984089682"></a>
              <a class="googleplus" href="http://googleplus.com/pages"></a>
             </div>

            <div id="wrap">
              <div id="featured">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <div class="textwidget">
                    <div class="cup">
                      <img src="..\Contrabang\img\red-cup.png" height="200">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div id="theFixed"><h1><a href="#">CONTRABANG</a></h1></div>

            <div class="bg1">

              <hgroup class="billboard second">
                <h2 style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 1; font-family: 'dosis'">
             We are an events management agency based in London. We create memorable experiences. Check out our upcoming event.</h2>

            </hgroup>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="pad">
             <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="..\Contrabang\img\Contrabang.jpg"  width="300" height="400"></a>
            </div>
                <h2 style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 1; font-family: 'dosis'">
             Buy Tickets: 07949747971</h2>
            </div>


            </div>

            </section>
```

& the main CSS

```
                  .main{text-align:center;}

                  #featured {
                    background: #E94F78 url(http://www.creativityfluid.com/wp-content/themes/creativityfluid/images/img-bubbles-red.png) no-repeat top;
                    background-size: 385px 465px;
                    color: #fff;
                    height: 535px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    position: relative;
                    z-index: -2;
                  }


                  #featured .wrap {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    clear: both;
                    padding: 70px 0 30px;
                    position: fixed;
                    z-index: -1;
                    width: 100%;
                  }


                  #featured .wrap .widget {
                    width: 80%;
                    max-width: 1040px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                  }

                  .textwidget{
                    padding: 0;
                  }


                  #wrap {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    padding: 0;
                  }

                  .cup{

                    margin-top:210px;
                  }


                  body, h1, h2, h3, p {
                    margin: 0; 
                    padding: 0;
                  }

                  a { 
                    text-decoration: none;
                  }

                  #theFixed{
                    position:fixed;
                    background-image:url(http://s10.postimg.org/wyyotlk15/krystalrae_2012_fall_print_leopard_sketch.jpg);
                    width:100%;
                    text-align:center;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    background-position: center;

                  }


                  h1{
                    font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
                    font-size:3.125em;
                    text-align:center;
                    padding:10px 10px;
                    margin:20px 20px;
                    background-color:#E94F78;
                    padding-left: 0.15em;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    display:inline-block;
                    color:yellow;

                  }

                  h1 a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    letter-spacing: 8px;
                            padding-left: 0.15em;
                    color:yellow;

                  }

                  .bg1{
                  background-image:url(http://www.coalmarch.com/sites/all/themes/coalmarch/images/paper-background-coalmarch-website-design.jpg);
                    width: 100%;
                    height:900px;

                    background-color: #e94f78;}

                  h2{

                  font-family: georgia;
                  font-size:3em;
                    color:black;
                  }


                  .billboard {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    width: 960px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                      text-align: center;
                  }

                  .pad{
                    padding:20px;
                  }
                  }

                  .billboard a {
                    color: #000000;   
                  }


                  .billboard {
                    padding-top:230px;
                  }
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to function in Moxilla". Could you be a bit more specific? I.e. tell us what you expect your code to do in Mozilla, and what it actually does.

Comment: Define "Does not function" - what differs between what you expect and what you want?

Comment: QUite a few issues with your HEAD such as trying to link to a file on your C: Drive and having your slashes in your file paths the wrong way round. Also some css errors. Run your page through this http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and this http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I've read all your suggestions and they've all helped. Firstly I deleted the C:drive, put the slashes the other way round, remove the unnecessary brackets within the css, and then ran it through the validators which was valid. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing this extra brace. FF might not be as forgiving as Chrome here:

```
              .pad{
                padding:20px;
              }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Links to your stylesheets are set the wrong way and I can imagine browsers handles this differently. also, you're trynig to load a file from your c:\drive, which is obviously not going to work